# Can UNIX Domain Sockets be locked by user ID?

Tags: operating-systems, unix, permissions, file-access

If I created a folder `/tmp/me` with permissions `700`, and started a process under `me` that starts a listen socket under `/tmp/me/socket`.

- I currently assume that a connection to that socket originated from a process that is running on the very same server (malicious or otherwise), and was not a connection from another server (unless through one of the processes).
- Can I also assume that the only users who can access that socket are `me`, and `root`?

I am asking about Solaris in particular.

**Note:** I'm aware that setting permissions on the `socket` file itself is not effective on various Operating Systems. That is why I chose to contain the `socket` file within a directory `me`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I currently assume that a connection to that socket originated from a process that is running on the very same server

Correct. Filesystem sockets must be read by a process that has access to the file.

> Can I also assume that the only users who can access that socket are me, and root?

Yes. Since `me` is the only user with permissions, they are the only ones who may enter that folder and view the socket. `root`, of course, is `root`.

Comment: There used to exist some Unix variants that ignored file permissions for local sockets. I can't remember which, though.

Comment: Within man unix under debian linux you can read  " This behavior differs from many BSD-derived systems which ignore permissions for UNIX domain sockets.  Portable programs should not rely on this feature for security." But context of this sentence starts wih "In the Linux implementation, sockets which are visible in the filesystem honor the permissions of the directory they are in." So i can't tell if it applies to unxid domain permissions or to directory owning unix domain entry...

Comment: well discussion is there : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83032/which-systems-do-not-honor-socket-read-write-permissions

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you *can* do this, but it may not be the best design since,  on some systems, [such as HP-UX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105925/91565), the permissions of the socket file are ignored.  While the permissions of the parent directory will still be applied, these may be harder to administer than the permissions on the socket file itself.

Unix domain sockets provide another means for verifying the identity of the remote process: `SCM_CREDENTIALS`, as documented in [`unix(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix).  This is foolproof since only root* is allowed to pass forged credentials.  Unfortunately, this does not appear to be any more standard than putting filesystem permissions on the socket file:

> `SCM_CREDENTIALS` and the abstract namespace were introduced with Linux 2.2 and should not be used in portable programs. (Some BSD-derived systems also support credential passing, but the implementation details differ.)

* On Linux, technically, the foreign process need only have the `CAP_SETUID` [capability](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities), but this is a root-equivalent capability under any vaguely reasonable system configuration anyway (in other words, if an attacker has that capability, they effectively have root).  The foreign process is also allowed to give you any of its [real, effective, and saved user/group IDs](http://linux.die.net/man/7/credentials), which is not a vulnerability either, [for similar reasons](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setresuid) (TL;DR: Any process is allowed to swap these credentials around whenever it likes).

Comment: *"Yes, you can do this, but it may not be the best design since, on some systems, such as HP-UX, the permissions of the socket file are ignored. "*. As per my understanding, the OP precisely set the right `700` on the parent folder (`/tmp/me`) and did not mentioned setting any right directly on the socket (`/tmp/me/socket`).

Comment: Thanks @WhiteWinterWolf. I've edited my question to clarify this for future visitors.